# converting from Object to string in java

Tags: java

I have this below method

```
public List<Object> ProductbyJobcode (String jobcode)
{
    List<Object> temp = new ArrayList<Object>();
    temp = riskJobCodeProductMappingDAO.fetchProductByJobCode(jobcode);
    return temp;
}
```

and i am taking the input in the Object list from the above method into Object type of list

```
List<Object> temp = new ArrayList<Object>() ;
temp = ProductbyJobcode(jobcode);
```

now i am trying to retrieve the value into string but i am getting exception, please advise how to achieve the same how i will convert the object to string

```
String Product ;
String Actiontype;

for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    product = temp.get(0).toString();
    Actiontype = temp.get(1).toString();
}
```

Comment: Please look up and use [proper Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/overview/index.html). Variables, fields and methods should be lowerCamelCase. It's confusing to read otherwise.

Comment: Which exception ?

Comment: What exception are you getting, and where?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: What is the size of your `temp` list?

Comment: if your list size is 1 then, you will get IndexOutOfBoundsException. check temp size.

Comment: I'm sure that the exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException caused by this line : Actiontype = temp.get(1).toString();

Answer (score 1):

`Object.toString()` could provide `NPE`. So more suitable method is `String.valueOf()`.

```
String Product = temp.size() >= 1 ? String.valueOf(temp.get(0)) : null;
String Actiontype = temp.size() >= 2 ? String.valueOf(temp.get(1)) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    product = temp.get(0).toString();
    Actiontype = temp.get(1).toString();
}
```

doesn't really test the bounds of the list correctly; you might only have one `String` in the list, which will mean `temp.get(1)` throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to achive, but this should work:

```
for (int i = 0; < temp.size; i++) {
    System.out.println(temp.get(0));
}
```

If you really need the two items, you probably want something like this

```
product = (temp.isEmpty()) ? null : temp.get(0).toString();
actionType = (temp.size() > 1) ? temp.get(1).toString() : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if your temp list contains only 1 element you try to get second element in this line:

```
Actiontype = temp.get(1).toString();
```

That cause:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Because you try to get second element when the list contains only one